# Python Django - Keep user log in session between views

Tags: python, django, authentication, view

I'm working on creating a method to log in users. I built a custom form and view and got the user to login fine. However, when I redirect to a new page, the current request.user automatically reverts back to AnonymousUser. What am I missing?

The log_in view logs in fine and I can even print the correct request.user. However, once it redirects to the log_in_success page, it simply says AnonymousUser is logged in! Why isn't the logged in user being preserved between views?

```
def log_in(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LogIn(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            email = form.cleaned_data.get("email")
            password = form.cleaned_data.get("password")
            user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)
            login(request, user)
            print request.user.email
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/log_in_success/')
    else:
        form = LogIn()
    return render(request, 'events/log_in.html', {'form':form})

def log_in_success(request):
    return HttpResponse("%s has logged in!" % request.user)
```

settings.py :

```
"""
Django settings for NHS project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.8.3.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os

#AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'events.Student'
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ('events.backend.StudentBackend', )

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '=6b_2=!3s2hq3-nc@#rx6v=##u53xt!b=(#)c(2nk%&4qfpvy)'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'events',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'NHS.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'NHS.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'nhs',
        'USER': 'nhsadmin',
        'PASSWORD': '#cbwestnhs',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Custom Authentication Backend:

```
from events.models import Student
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import check_password

class StudentBackend(object):

    def authenticate(self, email=None, password=None):
        stud = Student.objects.filter(email=email)
        if stud.exists():
            if check_password(password, stud[0].password):
                return stud[0]
        return None
    def get_user(self, email):
        stud = Student.objects.filter(email=email)
        if stud.exists():
            return stud[0]
        else:
            return None
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from events.models import Student
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import check_password

class RegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """
    Form for registering a new account.
    """
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput,
                                label="Password")
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput,
                                label="Password (again)")
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ('firstname', 'lastname', 'email', 'password1', 'password2', 'is_second_year')

    def clean(self):
        # Check that the two password entries match
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        email = self.cleaned_data.get("email")
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords don't match")
        if Student.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError("This email has already been registered")
        return self.cleaned_data

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(RegistrationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data['password1'])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user

class LogIn(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField(label = "Email")
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput, label="Password")

    def clean(self):
        password = self.cleaned_data.get("password")
        email = self.cleaned_data.get("email")
        stud = Student.objects.filter(email=email)
        if (not (stud.exists())):
            raise forms.ValidationError("This email has not been registered")
        else:
            if check_password(password, stud[0].password):
                pass
            else:
                raise forms.ValidationError("Email and password combination do not match.")
        return self.cleaned_data
```

Comment: not sure how much code is pertinent to this question, so let me know if there are any other files you'd like to see.

Comment: Did you try printing `user` which is returned after authenticate method? You might have to check `if user:` and then call the login method to login the user.

Comment: I print the user that is logged in on the initial log_in page and it is the correct user

Comment: is SessionMiddleware added to your MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES settings?

Comment: yes... "'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware'"

Comment: can you post your `settings.py` here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87422/discussion-between-anupsabraham-and-drsom).

Comment: Have you tested `user.is_active`?

Comment: yes and it is active

Answer (score 0):

I would try rearranging the `context_processors` and put auth on top. If that doesn't work, can you please post your custom authentication backend?

**settings.py:**

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                # Put auth on top
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Additionally, I would make the following changes to cleanup your views a little:

**views.py:**

```
from django.contrib import messages
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

def log_in(request):
    form = LogIn(request.POST or None)

    if form.is_valid():
        email = form.cleaned_data['email']
        password = form.cleaned_data['password']
        user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)

        # May also help with your dilemma
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            # Be sure to change this to the appropriate template name
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('template_name'))
        else:
            messages.warning(request, "Username or password is incorrect.")
    return render(request, 'events/log_in.html', {'form':form})

def log_in_success(request):
    # "{}".format(value) is a more reliable string substitution
    return HttpResponse("{} has logged in!".format(request.user))
```

**- - - EDIT:**

I would remove your custom backend and override the functions on your form instead. It'll save you a lot of trouble going forward.

```
class RegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(),
                                label="Password")
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(),
                                label="Password (again)")
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ('firstname', 'lastname', 'email', 'password1', 'password2', 'is_second_year')

    def clean_password2(self):
        # Check that the two password entries match
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        email = self.cleaned_data.get("email")
        if password1 and password2:
            if password1 != password2:
                raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords don't match")
        return password2

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
        if email and Student.objects.filter(email=email):
            raise forms.ValidationError("This email has already been registered")
        return email


class LogIn(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField(label="Email")
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(), label="Password")
```

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. Tried all you suggested, nothing worked :/. I posted my custom authentication backend.

Comment: @drsom Take a look at my edit. I strongly suggest you follow that method over the custom backend. Until you get more advanced, the custom backend is a bit overkill for what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your edits. Why would I throw an "Email is already registered error" in a log-in form? And what are the two passwords that are being checked against each other? The Log-in only has one.

Comment: @drsom Oops, the login form validations were my error. I just changed that. Tiredness catches up eventually.

Comment: I'm not sure what this is trying to do? The custom backend is necessary for my log in to work as I'm using a custom user type. And the clean method you removed from the login form is pretty necessary to show login errors. None of this seems to fix my original problem: why isn't the user login being preserved between views?

Answer (score 0):

You have to define your bakend into the settings.AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS list:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ['my_app.student_backend.StudentBackend']
```

Otherwise the `get_user` method in `django.contrib.auth` which contains the following lines:

```
user = None
...
if backend_path in settings.AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS:
    backend = load_backend(backend_path)
    user = backend.get_user(user_id)
    ...
return user or AnonymousUser()
```

would return `AnonymousUser()`

Optionally you can set your backend when calling `login` method (if there are more than one auth backends):

```
    if form.is_valid():
        email = form.cleaned_data.get("email")
        password = form.cleaned_data.get("password")
        user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)
        login(request, user, 'my_app.student_backend.StudentBackend')
        print request.user.email
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/log_in_success/')
```

This will save the given backend for this user into the session.